# Bootstrap 4 .card height limited by parent height when overflowed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to have a card deck with multiple cards in it, all side by side (even on mobile) with a horizontal and vertical scroll.

The cards' parent has a set height, and I can't manage to fit the card size (actually, borders) to the content of the card which is successfully placed "behind" the parent.

Here is my current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axel50397/eLrkasb0/

```
.h-scrollable {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.h-scrollable > .card {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do in the second paragraph, please explain in brief

Comment: Sorry I didn’t know how to explain it. I would like the .card to fit their content, therefore make “as if” they are behind the .card-deck. Currently .card’s size fit their parent

Comment: can you explain with images? with what you want and what you got

Comment: do you want to fit all buttons in your card?

Comment: Yes, I would like the content of the card (buttons or text) to visually be inside the card in a way that, to see the bottom of the card (and the rest of the content) it's necessary to scroll down vertically. Are images still necessary?

Comment: ok you need to set all buttons in card with fix height and scroll?

Comment: I answered your comment before seeing your answer. It's perfect (and exactly what I wanted), thank you

Comment: sorry, but correct answer is not mine

Comment: @NishargShah oups... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a container with the specific height that you want, and set `overflow-y: scroll` on that container:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="border-top border-bottom card-deck h-scrollable p-2 w-100">
        <div class="card mx-2">
            <div class="card-header">
                Wednesday 1 April 2020
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">12:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">14:00</button>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/uyox7zLt/2/

Comment: to be more precise please use `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: Is is possible de set the height to the height of one card, and keep to scrolling only on the others cards?